# How to delete the contents of all the files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, cp

Under `/tmp/REPORTS` I have a hundred files. What I want to do is erase the contents of each file in `/tmp/REPORTS` (not delete them). So I tried the following, but I get this error:

```
cp /dev/null /tmp/REPORTS/*

cp: Target /tmp/REPORTS/…..  must be a directory
Usage: cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] f1 f2
      cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] f1 ... fn d1
      cp -r|-R [-H|-L|-P] [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] d1 ... dn-1 dn
```

How can I clear the contents of all the files in the directory?

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to move the contents of `/tmp/Reports` to another location?

Comment: no , only I want is to clear the files content under REPORTS dir , not to move them

Comment: If you have GNU goodies, the fastest might be this: `truncate --size 0 /tmp/REPORTS/*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you want to truncate the contents of each file, you can do this:

```
for file in /tmp/REPORTS/*; do > "$file"; done
```

This will clear the contents of each file in the directory.

As [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) has suggested in the comments above, there is a GNU tool `truncate` that can do the job for you as well:

```
truncate --size 0 /tmp/REPORTS/*
```

This will possibly be quicker than looping through the files manually.

Comment: isnt not better to do --> for file in /tmp/REPORTS/*; do cp /dev/null  "$file"; done

Comment: @maihabunash if you want to empty each file, this is the standard way to do it.

Comment: ok , btw in many linux/solaris the command truncate not defined , so I will choose the first option , and +1 for you

Comment: Actually, it would only clear the first byte of the file.  OP asked to overwrite the file's contents with 0's.

Comment: For `truncate`, the manpage hints that blocks which were part of the file before are still present on the filesystem, containing the unerased data.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to be asking for what is termed a "secure erase".

While you cannot `cp /dev/null`, you could get the effect you are asking about using `dd`.  Here is a script to illustrate:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in $*
do
    test -h "$name" && continue
    test -f "$name" || continue
    blocks=`ls -s "$name" | awk '{print $1; }'`
    dd if=/dev/zero of="$name" count=$blocks
done
```

The script

- checks to ensure that the parameter is a regular file.
- then it asks for the number of *blocks* for the file.
- finally, it uses `dd` to copy 0's from the special device `/dev/zero`.

This relies on `dd` and `ls` having the same notion of blocksize (which appears to be the case).  It also assumes that the filesystem does not reallocate blocks for a given file, i.e., that they can be reliably overwritten in-place.  If you want a better guarantee, there are other solutions, e.g., this discussion of [Secure Erase in UNIX](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/secure-erase.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
for remove

```
find /tmp/REPORTS/ -type f -name "*.*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or move them to some where you want 
for cp

```
find /tmp/REPORTS/ -type f -name "*.*" -exec cp {} \tmp\{} \;
```

for mv

```
find /tmp/REPORTS/ -type f -name "*.*" -exec mv {} \dev\null \;
```

Comment: I dont whant to delete the files , what I need is to erase them as cp /dev/null ,

Comment: You mean: `-exec cp /dev/null {} \;` and your `-name "*.*"` is (wrong and) useless.

Comment: see my answer i know that !

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`$ find /tmp/REPORTS/ -type f -exec cat /dev/null > {} \;`

Or if you have a large number of files, try using   `\+`  instead of `\;` for a more efficient commandline.